Adding bank account to Apple Store Connect Not working
I spent hours trying to add a bank account to app store connect account.
I tried with a local bank and international bank, nothing works. Same error message:

I checked the logs, here is the error code.
{
    "message": [
        {
            "type": "error",
            "attributeName": "bankBranchIdentification1",
            "messageKey": "PPM.banking.localclearnacecode.search.notFoundByQuery"
        }
    ]
}

When I click for search for your bank, it shows no results and the same errors.

I found other users facing the same issue on Reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/
This problem is preventing me from setting up in-app purchases. My entire team is unable to work on the implementation and testing of our in-app purchases due to this issue, and we are currently blocked. Is there a way to get them to assist with this urgently ?
I called them but they said I need to email the finance department but they are taking 2 days to reply now.

I definitely think this is a technical problem caused by Apple, and although this problem has been going on since last week. It's obvious that https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ppm/v1/banking/search endpoint returns a 400 Bad Request error no matter what country code or word you type. As you mentioned, there have been posts on different platforms about this issue. I also sent an e-mail to the Apple Finance team through this means, I hope they can solve this problem manually. My advice to you is to definitely open a support request to the finance team. https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/co

seems to work as of now

I agree. With all that $99/year, I'd expect some higher quality developer portal

same error for Indonesia Banks. Still didn't work.

Open a support request @СергейКозлов - as you see above, the issue was fixed server side within hours of this post. With WWDC imminent , one could presume they are making changes behind the scenes for launch. Also, check https://developer.apple.com/system-status/ for issues announced and being worked on
